# Can the formula for the sum of the first n squares be deduced from the known value of zeta of 2?

Tags: number-theory

I know this is asking that we swat a fly with a sledge hammer, but this off-the-wall question is prompted by the fact that they both have 6 in the denominator. That is, is that common 6 in the denominator the tip of the ice berg of a direct connection between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that common $6$ in the denominator the tip of the ice berg of a direct connection between them?

Yes. See [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number). In particular, the [values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers) of $\zeta(2n)$, as well the [Faulhaber's formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) for

the sums of *k*-th powers of the first *n* natural numbers, depend on them. In this case, $B_2=\dfrac16$